# How to get the dom's parent when we use datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

[image]

I encountered a issue that when i used datepickcker.js,clicked the next btn but i could not get it(span.ui-icon.ui-icon-circle-triangle-e)'s grandfather"div .ui-datepicker-inline.ui-datepicker.ui-widget .ui-widget-content.ui-helper-clearfix.ui-corner-all".

see my picture,it's clear.

Comment: Instead of using that chain of parent(), use : https://api.jquery.com/parents/. And also, Post a fiddle. That will also help us to dig in the problem

Comment: Provide jsFiddle replicating issue because your posted sample should work as expected

Comment: why don't you just use target.closest('.ui-datepicker')

Comment: i had used target.closest('.ui-datepicker') ,but the result is target.closest('.ui-datepicker').length==0,which is wrong